# logging static methods in a parent class

Tags: java, static, log4j

I have an abstract class Parent, with 2 subclasses A and B. Parent has one static method called do(). I am wondering if there is a way for that static method to add log info in Logger for class A when it's called as A.do() and log B when it's called as B.do(). The usual

```
protected final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
```

won't work as do() is a static method so Logger needs to be static as well, but the getClass() method is obviously not static.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is the method static? Make it non-static.

Comment: @Sudhanshu - why would you need an abstract method `getClass`?  that is already built into every object.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Removing the static is the obvious way, but I would like it to stay as the method is not related to any instances of the class, but the class itself.

Comment: @jtahlborn My bad, just skipped that. You are right, its not required.

Comment: A.do() doesn't resolve to Parent.do(), "when it's called as A.do" doesn't make sense. Add more code to clarify what you want.

Comment: it does make sense. A.do() can be used to call the static method of the Parent class, in the same way as Parent.do(). I can add an example for you as well if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it, but if you really want it...

```
public class A {
  public static void do() {
    doImpl(A.class);
  }
  protected static void doImpl(Class<?> refClass) {
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  public static void do() {
    doImpl(B.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: heh! seems like this could work :D but I wouldn't do that either. So do you think I am correct in saying that my alternatives are the following:

Comment: a) Just log the static methods in the Parent class. b) copy the whole static method in all children classes c) make the method not be static

Comment: @sakiskaliakoudas -  i would agree with a,c.  if you were going to do b, i would recommend my answer above.  bute yes, those are pretty much your options.

Answer (score 2):

`private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(A.class);`

Every class having its own `logger`: specifying the class is fine.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work either as the static method that uses the LOGGER is in the parent class. Every time it is called regardless of where it is called from it will use the Parent Logger, not the logger of the sub classes.

Comment: Le me insist :) : every class should have its own logger declared, the parent and the subclass. You do not inherit loggers.

Comment: I agree with you that every class should have a logger. So even if every class has a logger, how would you make it so that the static method that exists in the parent class logs the information in the sub class logger?

Comment: Wait. The subclass does not use the parent logger. It has its own logger and uses that. So when you call `log.info(...)` in child B you actually use the final static logger declared at the top of B which logs in category `B.class` so your log contains the correct category/class name. Or are we confusing sub-classes and class instances here ?

Comment: probably : ) The log.info() that you mentioned is inside a static method that exists only in the parent class, does that make things more clear? As a sequence of that, the log is always the parent log

Comment: We have a disconnect here. if B inherits from A and B has its own logger declaration as above (private final static LOGGER etc..), any call in B of `LOGGER.info(...)`  will use the the `LOGGER` declared in B, not in A (where it is private anyway)

Comment: haha :D So imagine that: 2 classes A and B. Class A only has one logger and one static method called "do()" and in that method some things are logged. Class B inherits from A and has one Logger but nothing else in it whatsoever. Then someone in a test case calls both A.do() and B.do(). I want the A.do() to be logged against logger in class A and b.do() to be logged against logger in class b. Makes sense ?

Comment: then you cannot have static loggers or you have to overwrite do() in B but... the good news is that good logging frameworks like log4j will report that the category is com.mycompany.A but the class is com.mycompany.B because the class is determined at runtime (this is an expensive call though so it really depends where and how you stick the call)

Answer (score -1):

Best practice is to declare LOGGER static, e.g.

```
protected final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
```

This way you can use LOGGER from dynamic and static methods.

Also each class should have its own instance of the logger. So I would change protected to private.

ALSO, instead of calling "getClass()" you should call "MyApp.class", e.g.

```
private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyApp.class);
```

Comment: @sakis kaliakoudas I've updated my answer with the example how to reference you class name for the logger (its the best practice from log4j creators)

Comment: this would mean that everything is written in the logger of that class, "MyApp.class" in your example, where I want some things to be written in the subclasses when the method calls are from the subclasses

Comment: Again every class should use its own logger instance. In the sublclass u dont use parent logger... instead you use your current logger defined in your class...this is standard practice in Java. You can read more from log4j documentation on this topic:  http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html