# Creating a Logger static implementation

Tags: java, logging

I'm currently looking to implement a logging class for a semi-large project I am working on. My implementation is something like this...

```
//In the primary driver class
public static final Logger log = new Logger(/*logger config*/);

//In subclasses
DriverClass.log(/*log inputs*/);
```

That being said, I recently came across some articles that mentioned having a logger in each individual class. Is this a better implementation then I am currently working with? (Reference: [logging static methods in a parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571950/logging-static-methods-in-a-parent-class)). It seems from most references I find that this is the proper way to do it, so inherently why is my method of calling it from a different class wrong?

Also as an aside, my implementation also has various levels of logs (Debug, Info, etc). I was wondering if its a good practice to assign a severity to each log type as well. I'll write out an example below...

**Error (Severity 1)** - Needs to be addressed, but not a critical system failure (e.g. a customer managed to create a bad configuration that caused problems for them).

**Error (Severity 5)** - The entire system crashed, nothing is running.

I have seen some people do things similar to this (http://docs-legacy.fortinet.com/frec/admin_hlp/1-1-0/index.html#page/FortiRecorder_Help/about_log_severity_levels.html) where a severity level indicates the "type" of issue, however I should clarify that I mean to combine both, as opposed to using one or the other.

Comment: Why not just use the java.util.Logging framework for this?

Comment: Its just a personal "for fun" project, so I am mostly looking to build experience and learn as much as possible on a larger then normal project. Part of that is to make everything from scratch to learn about implementation. The logger functionality is one of those things.

Comment: There is many existing logger projects, even projects to consolidate these. f you are not going to use them, I suggest you at least read up on their design if not read their code to see what you might do better.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That still brings me back to my question though, for instance, the util.Logging framework uses the typical levels which seem to be for the most part standard for java. Would adding a severity level on top be a good framework addition (I believe so else I would not ask, but am looking for reasons it might not be). Similarly the implementation of util.Logging could be the same as what I mentioned above, or could be called in each class. I can't find something that clearly states which is better. --Edit I have changed the question slightly

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr a logging level is a simple filter.  You could have a multi-dimensional filter for example, though it might be too complicated to filter.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You might be right, although I am starting to think its just a complication that adds too much detail for something that should be simple. E.g. if I need two levels of severity for an error I should just have ERROR and ERROR_SEVERE as opposed to having an additional parameter to separably save the severity.

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr the main levels are; messages you are likely to only turn on in development, messages you are likely to use in production, messages which probably means a user needs to fix/handle it. e.g. Ops. i.e. think of it in terms how many different actions you are likely to take and give each a different "level"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a logger per class would allow for more granularity in your logs. For instance, you could have messages of the following structure: `[DATE] [CLASS NAME] [SEVERITY] [MESSAGE]`. Having the class name in your logs could save time in trying to dig out from where is the actual log being generated.

As another side rule, having a class name could also allow you to control what can each class emit to your log. Consider deploying a class which communicates with 3rd parties. For the first time or so, you would be emitting information logs to console to see how things are going on live environment. If/when you see that everything is going fine, you would simply turn off information messages for that particular class, instead of doing another deployment wherein you removed your message logs.

Comment: I can see why that would be a benefit. I recently read this (http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/23/avoid-java-static-logger.html) that detailed a better way to use a single static logger class, but honestly after reading your answer I think having a bit more granularity would be preferred.